# hide active click events and then to reappear

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of buttons that show and hide corresponding divs. I would like the buttons, once clicked, to be hidden but to show again when another button is clicked. I hope that the following plunk will make this clearer.

**[Plunk Link](http://embed.plnkr.co/iMavuVmaid0mtRceB2T1/preview)**

Currently my buttons hide once clicked, but do not reappear when other buttons are clicked. How can I do this?

```
<div id="div1" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum1</div>
<div id="div2" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum2</div>
<div id="div3" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum3</div>
<div id="div4" class="targetDiv">Lorum Ipsum4</div>

<div class="showSingle" target="1"><a>Div 1</a></div>
<div class="showSingle" target="2"><a>Div 2</a></div>
<div class="showSingle" target="3"><a>Div 3</a></div>
<div class="showSingle" target="4"><a>Div 4</a></div>
```

---

```
<script>

$(function(){

        $('.showSingle').click(function(){
              $('.targetDiv').hide();
              $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
              $(this).hide();
              $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
        });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('.showSingle:hidden').add(this).toggle();` to show the previously hidden div.

The `:hidden` searches for hidden element and `add()` to add current element. `toggle()` changes element state hide/show depending on current state.

```
$(function(){
     $('.showSingle').click(function(){
         $('.targetDiv').hide();
         $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
         $('.showSingle:hidden').add(this).toggle();
         $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
     });
});
```

**[Updated Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/7OcpmRchHwPpyoABwA69?p=preview)**

or making it more shorter,

```
$('.showSingle').click(function(){
    $('.targetDiv:visible').add($('#div'+$(this).attr('target'))).toggle();
    $('.showSingle:hidden').add(this).toggle();

    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.showSingle').click(function(){
              $(".showSingle").show();
              $('.targetDiv').hide();
              $('#div'+$(this).attr('target')).show();
              $(this).hide();
              $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
        });
```